# Why is uploading files from a browser always slow?

Tags: networking, browser, ftp, upload

An experience that does not surprise me at all after ten years of using the internet:

I'm uploading a 16GB dataset to a website (Kaggle). When using their online interface for the upload, the file starts to upload at first but eventually hangs after only about 400MB. I'm left looking at the upload bar, checking my network upload and waffling on whether or not the connection broke and I should reload the page to try again. When I use the Kaggle API and upload the file from the a terminal window, it smoothly and consistently uploads at about 30MB/s.

I can recall having similar experiences in the past using FTP. Is there some limiting factor for browsers or web design that means uploading files through a web interface will always be terrible?

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate attempts:

1. Via the browser.
2. Via API.

And possible factors:

a. The difference is when they are tried. (say 3 hours or 5 minutes
apart)

b. General internet status in related processes ( a huge
topic, and factor )

c. Intensity of Kaggle's (server load, especially
down-link load, during trials at different times)

In this case, as a search for a solution
In order to expand the number of experiments and observation range,
After installing 3-4 of the main stream browsers,
I would try again, separately, what you tried.

Depending on the importance of the situation, it is possible to try to find a sensible idea in the light of what I have stated, or a way to just upload via API from now on. (One of the API testing tools can help you figure this out)

Finally, Asking for support from Kaggle will also create a chance for a solution.